# pid-file parameter being ignored in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, linux, database-administration, superuser

As the title says, I am having issues in Mysql 5.7 getting the startup script to recognize the pid-file value i am placing in my.cnf.

```
[root@testbox01 local]# /usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
```

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

in my current /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]

pid-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid

[mysqld_safe]

pid-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid
```

However

```
mysql> select @@pid_file;
+----------------------------+
| @@pid_file                 |
+----------------------------+
| /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I saw Bug #84172 The pid-file value is ignored in the `/etc/my.cnf` option file but it mentions placing the pid-file value under `[mysqld_safe]` which i am also doing. Does anyone have further insight or thoughts on this?

Comment: Might have better luck on superuser or DBA

Comment: Fixed this eventually by using systemd rather than init scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the default init scripts, I wrote a unit for mysql using systemd. pid is being placed with no issues now.